# Display problem after upgrade to Ubuntu 14.04.3

Tags: 14.04, drivers, graphics, ati, radeon

After installing the latest Ubuntu 14.04.3 on my old Laptop (Toshiba Satellite) i have some issues with the display.

There is flickering (like in a white noise) on the screen, and it is bugging me and my eyesight.

I am using the open source radeon driver, since the propretary amd/ati driver is not supported anymore for my graphic card and ubuntu 14.04.3, which is an "AMD/ATI RV730/M96 Mobility Radeon HD 4650/5165".

My current linux kernel version is "3.19.0-30-generic". (I tried updating it to a newer version 4.2.3, but it didn't help either)

The curious thing is, that I had already had Ubuntu 14.04(.0 i suppose) installed on this exact computer, and there were no such issues. There is also Win8.1 running on this machine, where this problem does not occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really seems to be a problem with the kernel - I now reverted my setup to Ubuntu 14.04.1 which supports the 3.13 kernel until 2019 and seems to have no problems with displaying everything correctly.